# How can I get bigger Ubuntu logo at the top menu in 11.04 

Tags: icons, panel, customization

I have made my panel bigger and all the icons also get bigger except one, the logo on the left of the main menu that says "Applications Places System". Is there a way to make that logo/icon the same size as the other icons on panel? I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and gnome not unity.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 comes with an immature version of Unity and it is highly recommended that you upgrade to 12.04, also because 11.04 reaches EOL in October.

Comment: +1 to Upgrade to 12.04. But if you're dead set on sticking with 11.04, please upload a screenshot to help identify the problem and a potential solution.

Comment: To tell you the truth , that depends upon **Icon theme** mostly :)

Comment: I did not want to go to 12.04 because i just got everything the way i want and installed in this one .. now i have to do it again ....Anyway i do not like unity at all, and i will upload a screen shot later .. thanks